# Is it possible to set up a VueJS2 development environment on an external SSD or USB?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is it possible to set up a VueJS2 development environment on an external SSD or USB without having NodeJS, NPM and Webpack installed globally on the machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Change npm scripts to run from the local installation of that node module. For example, node_modules/.bin/webpack.